# DBeaver Project export Driver Version

Tags: dbeaver

When exporting/importing a DBeaver project, the connections' driver is included in the "data-sources.json".  However there is no version specified so on import, the latest version of the driver is downloaded.
I was hoping that we could explicitly specify a particular version.

Can't find any documentation on what attribute to add, or even it it would work.
Blindly tried adding "version" but it just fell flat on it's face.
Has anyone tried this  or know of other useful info ?

Thanks

```
"connections": {
        "postgres-redshift-jdbc-18c40a1a63e-11fd252a6d9dc233": {
            "provider": "postgresql",
            "driver": "postgres-redshift-jdbc",
            "name": "Development SSO",
            "version_required_here": "2.1.0.21"
```